# VIM better way to replace line from the first symbol

Tags: vim, text-editor, vi

Having the code:

```
[Test]
public void ShouldDoSomethingMeaningFull() {
    Assert.Fail();
}
```

I often need to overwrite the line (3) `Assert.Fail();`. What I currently do is this:

1. Go to that line `3G`.
2. Select everything starting from first non-whitespace `^v$`.
3. Change it - `c`.

The whole sequence is: `3G^v$c`.

While this works for me but it is not efficient way of doing it because my fingers jump to the ^ and $.

Any better way?

Thanks,
Dmitriy.

Comment: This isn't really a programming question. It's a vi question, or more generally, a "how do I use a piece of software" question. Voting to send to Super User (despite this post being a little old).

Comment: VIM is not just a "piece of software". It's a programmer tool. The best prove is the number of "VIM" questions on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The obvious improvement would be <kbd>3</kbd><kbd>G</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> (C means change to end of line, i.e. the same as <kbd>3</kbd><kbd>G</kbd><kbd>c</kbd><kbd>$</kbd>)

If you prefer to change the entire line as pointed out by Pavel Shved, there's a not so obvious shortcut for that as well. <kbd>3</kbd><kbd>G</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> is the same as <kbd>3</kbd><kbd>G</kbd><kbd>c</kbd><kbd>c</kbd>.

The "Making small changes" section of the help file has more details.

Comment: Nice. I'll try to use that myself.

Comment: Nice one, provided that `G` always jumps to the first non-whitespace position in the line (which seems like it does).

Answer (score 4):

The correct key combo would be <kbd>3</kbd><kbd>G</kbd><kbd>c</kbd><kbd>c</kbd>.

<kbd>c</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> will replace the whole line (contrary to  <kbd>C</kbd>, which only replaces starting from the current character), and will preserve whitespaces at the beginning of the line.

Comment: Nice one. I gues the `cc` and `C` (suggested by Brian Rasmussen) are the same.

Comment: @Dmitriy, it is the same, unless `startofline` is set, which makes `G` keep the column.  I prefer setting it, personally.

Comment: `C` will replace from current character to the end. `cc` will replace the entire line, regardless of cursor location.

Comment: Also `C` will leave cursor at current position, while `cc` puts it to the first column (as the line is no blank).

Comment: `cc` and `S` only preserve indentation when `autoindent` is on, which if you're editing code, it probably is.

Answer (score 3):

I like to use `S`, which deletes the line and places you in insert mode, preserving indenting. While `C` works as well, `S` works from any position in the line.

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work as `S` puts the cursor at the beginning of the line (first column) and will not set it to the first non-whitespace character.

Comment: @Dmitriy Nagirnyak - it should work for the syntax you posted above. Try turning on c indenting: :set cin

Answer (score 2):

For me, it's quicker to just do:

```
3GddO
```

Which goes to the line 3 `3G`, deletes that line `dd`, and inserts a line above the current line (the closing brace now) `O`

Comment: Using `O` is potentially buggy on some terminals (https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=169396).  I think, a better option should be considered.

Comment: that's why I filed it to KDE bugzilla. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

3GC  - makes most sense to me. Easier than having to into visual mode.